# Open file Dialog Filter Hides Everything WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, openfiledialog

I have OpenFileDialog. when i set Filter to opd to only show files with 'x' extension it will hide every thing.

im new to WPF. i didnt put opd Control (like in WinForm) inside WPF because i couldnt find it.

OpenFileDialog works fine when i set filter to * . * to show all files.

i Checked the extension of files and it was correct.

also i searched in for this problem and didnt find anything.

thanks for help.

```
        OpenFileDialog opd = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            FileName = "X File",
            DefaultExt = ".x",
            Filter = "X Files (*.x)|*.x | All Files (*.*)|*.*",
            Multiselect = true
        };

        bool? result = opd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            //...
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change your filter from

```
"X Files (*.x)|*.x | All Files (*.*)|*.*"
```

To

```
"X Files (*.x)|*.x|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
```

As stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Do not put spaces before or after the vertical bars in the filter
>   string. This will cause incorrect behavior in the filter.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - Yes, and believe me or not, unfortunately little mistakes are very hard to spot :)

Comment: Yes yes. i believe you and they are hardest.this happened to me losts of times xD @Sébastien Sevrin

Answer (score 0):

I was using "game config files|*.cfg|All files| ***.** "

Selecting star.star hid all files instead of showing them.
Fixed it by removing the TRAILING SPACE from the filter string.